# Can I group-aggregate-calculate from another table directly in razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, aggregate

Snip of code as example:

controller:

```
var author = context.Authors.Include(a => a.Books);
```

razorview:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.BooksNavigation.Id.COUNT()
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

I need result in screen by Author:

```
Author   Books
-------  -----
Author1    3
Author2    4
...
```

So, is it possible simplify Linq, don't create additional viewmodel and COUNT() directly to screen only?

I've made some modifies based on answers

Comment: That should be giving you an exception (you cannot us a method in an expression)

Comment: You can of course just use `<td>@item.Books.Count()</td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to display count of books,

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.Books.COUNT()
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: I need to display count of books by author

Comment: @user1855805 `Books` is navigation property of Authers so Books property has books of the perticular auther